# Installing a module/script in Python on OSX

Tags: python, macos, module, installation

I am running Python 2.6.2 in Mac OSX 10.5.8.

I am trying to generate scientific graphs for a publication and am experimenting with python/matplotlib to do that.  Varun Hiremath created a module called plot_settings.py ([link text](http://eccentric.mae.cornell.edu/~vh63/matplotlib.html) and I am trying to figure out how to install the module so that I can import it.  I'm not sure if easy_install is applicable here, which is why I'm confused.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put that file in the same folder as your script and import it: `import plot_settings`.